# Objects overwritten PHP

Tags: php, oop

I've two classes which extend another class.

But when the second object is instantiated gets the definitions of the first.

Object  B gets the definitions of the object A

Class A

```
class a extends Connection{

    public function __construct() { parent::__construct("TOKENS");}

    public function helloA(){
        echo "A";
    }
}
```

Class B

```
class B extends Connection{

    public function __construct() { parent::__construct("USERLEVEL"); }

    public function helloB(){
        echo "B";
    }
}
```

Class Connection

```
class Connection extends dbData{

    private $table;

    function __construct($name){
        $this->setTable($name);
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function setTable($name){
        $this->table = parent::getTable($name);
    }

    public function connectionInsert($info){
        return parent::insert($this->table, $info);
    }

    public function connectionSelect($where="", $bind="", $fields="*"){
        return parent::select($this->table, $where, $bind, $fields);
    }

    public function connectionDelete($where, $bind=""){
        return parent::delete($this->table, $where, $bind);
    }

    public function connectionRun($sql, $bind=""){
        return parent::run($sql, $bind);
    }

    public function connectionEdit($info, $where, $bind){
        return parent::update($this->table, $info, $where, $bind);
    }


}
```

Testing File

```
   $a = new a();
   print_r($a);
   $b = new b();
   print_r($b);
```

Results:

```
a Object ( [table:Connection:private] => tokens [error:Db:private] => [sql:Db:private] => [bind:Db:private] => [errorCallbackFunction:Db:private] => [errorMsgFormat:Db:private] => )
a Object ( [table:Connection:private] => tokens [error:Db:private] => [sql:Db:private] => [bind:Db:private] => [errorCallbackFunction:Db:private] => [errorMsgFormat:Db:private] => )
```

But if i do a print_r directly of the new A() or new B()

```
print_r(new a());
print_r(new b());
```

The result is what i want to get.

```
a Object ( [table:Connection:private] => tokens [error:Db:private] => [sql:Db:private] => [bind:Db:private] => [errorCallbackFunction:Db:private] => [errorMsgFormat:Db:private] => )
B Object ( [table:Connection:private] => us_level [error:Db:private] => [sql:Db:private] => [bind:Db:private] => [errorCallbackFunction:Db:private] => [errorMsgFormat:Db:private] => )
```

Even when i'm trying to access the functions of each class, suddenly i've got the error saying that function doesn't exist on that class.

Testfile

```
$a = new a();
print_r($a->helloA());

$b = new b();
echo "</br>";
print_r($b->helloB());
```

Error Message:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method a::helloB()
```

So, at this point i've no clue why i'm getting the objects overwritten.

Anybody can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I copy/pasted your code in my IDE and ran but no problem here! so it's very strange that when you create object B, you get error that object A method (a::helloB()) does'n exist! If you put whole codes (inclusive  dbData) i am willing to try it again..

Comment: I haven't tried, but I do think that the issue might be in the names that the OP anonymized.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks everybod!! It was a problem in the PHP-PDO class. I've replaced that one by another and worked!!!